# using update immutablity helper I get eslint error : Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Thanks in advance. I use immutability - helper to set the state. But i get eslint error near `this.setState` It says : `Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state`
Is there any work around since i use immutablity helper do i need to use `prevState`
Can any share corrected methods.

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

moveSection = (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
    const { list} = this.state;
    const dragCard = list[dragIndex];

    this.setState(
      update(this.state, {
        list: {
          $splice: [
            [dragIndex, 1],
            [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard],
          ],
        },
      }),
    ); };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.setState(
  (state) => {
     return update(state, {
       list: {
         $splice: [
           [dragIndex, 1],
           [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard],
         ],
       },
     })
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you to do this:

```
this.setState(prevState => 
  update(prevState, {
    list: {
      $splice: [
        [dragIndex, 1],
        [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard],
      ],
    },
  }),
);
```

If the state is changed multiple times in rapid succession, react may batch these changes and apply them all in a single render. As a result, if you call `update` and pass in `this.state`, you're not guaranteed that `this.state` has the most recent state, so you could end up throwing out changes that were made by another state update.

If instead you use the function version of setState, then you *are* guaranteed to be given the most recent state and this possible bug is eliminated.

Comment: Well, i'm glad that the other answer worked for you. It's weird that it's identical to mine in all relevant ways and yet mine doesn't work. Next time, please provide more information. I can't do anything to improve the answer if all you tell me is "this doesn't work".

Comment: @Nicolas Tower, thanks for the answer. I will dive into this more. This was resulting in a UI issue. I was using drag and drop. Using your code the drag and drop was not working. I could find any error. Sorry for the short reply. I appreciate your quick response.